# What would be a good alternative to the phrase "tip-top"?

Tags: phrase-requests, catch-phrases

I have a friend who is writing a story and he has thus far come up with unique catch-phrases that each of his characters uses throughout the story.

For example:

> keep it ominous

and

> you're so flow

For this specific character, he was going to use

> I keep it tip-top

but we both agreed that it's ultimately too generic of a term (I'm his editor). We're looking for something along the lines of tip-top, but more unique/original. Any suggestions?

Comment: "spiffy"? "spic and span"? "well oiled"?

Comment: I keep it peak. / I keep it capital. / I floss it ride good, old bean.

writers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Consider *tickety-boo* for this character's catch-phrase, as in "**I keep it tickety-boo"**.

**Tickety-boo:** (adj.) "*British, old fashioned, informal* -- as it should be; correct, satisfactory". (Collins Dictionary)

It rolls off the tongue with the addition of the word *all* as in "I keep it **all** tickety-boo".

Answer (score 0):

> I keep it at the zenith.

The meaning (of ***zenith***) fits:

> [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/zenith):
>
>   the highest point; peak; acme ⇒
>   *the zenith of someone’s achievements*
>
> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zenith):
>
>   - the highest point reached in the heavens by a celestial body
>
>     culminating point : acme
>       <at the *zenith* of his powers — John Buchan>
>
> [Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/zenith):
>
>   The time at which something is most powerful or successful:
>   *‘in 1977, punk was at its zenith’*

[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tip-top%2Czenith&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctip%20-%20top%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Czenith%3B%2Cc0) says that *zenith* is declining in popularity,
so it might qualify as distinctive (unique/original)
while also being readily understood.

In addition, (IMO) the phrase has a certain lyrical property:
“keep it” and “zenith” sound similar. 
If your friend replaced “I” with two syllables, e.g.,

> Always keep it at the zenith.

it would be a syllabically-balanced almost-rhyme.

Comment: I really like that! I should have clarified initially though - this specific character is an orphan who never got an education, so she doesn't have a very expansive vernacular. therefore, we've got to keep it relatively simple..